# Groovy: how to access inner variables?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to access a variable which is getting defined inside a loop. How can I access it?

```
fileContents.split('\n').each {
    if (it =~ /nodePort:/) {
        def splitted_string = it.split(':')
        String nodePort = (splitted_string[1].trim())
    }
}
println nodePort
```

> Error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: nodePort

How do I access variable nodePort?

Comment: what's `splitted_string`?

Comment: Added the code for splitted_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access variables from the outer scope. However, you can move the variable to the outer scope.

```
String nodePort
fileContents.split('\n').each {
    if (it =~ /nodePort:/) {
        nodePort = (splitted_string[1].trim())
    }
}
println nodePort
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
fileContents.split('\n').find { it =~ /nodePort:/ }?.tokenize(":")?.getAt(1)
```